# Error when send request from partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, partial-views

I'm trying to learn the basics of MVC (NerdDinner tutorial). I have defined a model:

```
public class DinnerFormViewModel
{

    // Properties
    public Dinner Dinner { get; private set; }

    public SelectList Countries { get; private set; }

    // Constructor
    public DinnerFormViewModel(Dinner dinner)
    {
        Dinner = dinner;
        Countries = new SelectList(PhoneValidator.Countries, dinner.Country);
    }
}
```

and I defined a partial view:

```
 @model MyNerddiner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel



 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Dinner</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Dinner.DinnerID)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

which is loaded from usual view:

```
 @model MyNerddiner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 } 
 <div id="Create" > 
 <h2>Host a Dinner</h2>

   @Html.Partial("_DinnerForm")

 </div>
```

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    Dinner dinner = new Dinner()
    {
        EventDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
    };
    return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(DinnerFormViewModel dinnerViewModel)
{
    Dinner dinner = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            dinner = dinnerViewModel.Dinner;
            UpdateModel(dinner);
            dinnerRepository.Add(dinner);
            dinnerRepository.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = dinner.DinnerID });
        }
        catch
        {
            ModelState.AddRuleViolations(dinner.GetRuleViolations());
            return View(dinner);
        }
    }
    return View(new DinnerFormViewModel(dinner));
}
```

Now when I'm trying to create (on postback), I'm getting an error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

I can guess that it is because somewhere the program is trying to initiate the `DinnerFormViewModel`, but where, and why and how should I make it right?

Answer (score 0):

The MVC framework needs your view model to have a constructor that takes no parameters so that it can create an empty instance to populate with data from the request.  DinnerFormViewModel does not implement a constructor with no parameters, add one, and this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you , but even after created another parameterless constructor of DinnerFormViewModel i'm getting the same error. Now it happening somwhere in linq generated class.

Comment: By the way question: why create an empty instance to populate with data from the request, when the instance was already created in first routing?

Comment: The instance is only created when the routing finds a pattern in the request that matches the expected method parameter.

Comment: Is there another object in your model hierarchy that doesn't have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: May be i'm wrong when i'm trying to get DinnerFormViewModel in httpPost instead of Dinner

Comment: I see now in the nerdinners code the parameter of HttpPost handler is Dinner. But now i'm getting Error:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyNerddiner.Models.Dinner' but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyNerddiner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the problem and it have nothing to do with model and constructor.

the problem was that view contained following row:
    
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Countries,  Model.Countries)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Countries)
    
When i checked from where the exception came- it come because the country value was null.

After i changed
    model => model.Countries
to
    model => model.Dinner.Country

the exception stoped to be thrown

I'm so glad i solve this on my own!